# Python function to create an array of particular column of csv file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv

I need to write a function that, given a CSV file name as a string and a column number, will create an array with the distinct values in that particular column of the file. Assuming my first column is 0 just like in Python lists. This file also has a header and footer row.

```
import csv

def facet(file, column):
    """ (str, int) -> array
Gets a list of distinct values from the specified column in the input file.
"""
```

Comment: Well then my advice would be to start writing. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. What have you tried? Have you looked at the built-in `csv` module? Do you have a question about how to use it? Please be specific. Also, when you say `array`, do you mean a Python `list`? Because they are not the same thing.

Comment: So what's you actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import csv

def facet(file, column):
    with open(file, newline='') as f_input:
        return [row[column] for row in csv.reader(f_input)][1:-1]

print(facet('input.csv', 1))
```

The reads the file as a `csv` and uses a list comprehension to select only only cell from each row and build a list. Finally `[1:-1` is used to skip over header and footer in your file.